# When are persisted computed columns updated?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, calculated-columns

Running `SQL Server 2014`. [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx) states that the values of computed columns marked as `PERSISTED` are *"updated when any columns that are part of their calculation change"*. Are they referring to the *entire column* of a table or the *actual row*?

**E.g.** If I have a table `T` with a persisted computed column `Bar` as shown below, will `Bar` be recalculated if I insert a new row into `T`? (The entire colum does change, but not the actual row.)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Baz(@foo INT)
RETURNS INT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @foo % 10 -- Could be more complex! E.g. SELECT ...
END
GO

CREATE TABLE T 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Foo INT NOT NULL,
    Bar AS dbo.Baz(Foo) PERSISTED
)
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed columns are *meant* to only depend on other column values within the same row (plus expressions, constants, etc). As such, your question does not make much sense.

However, some people do "clever" things by using UDFs so that they can access other data within other tables or for other rows within the same table as part of their computed column definition. SQL Server isn't aware of this "cleverness" and so, if the UDF is accessing other data, no, it's not guaranteed to update such a computed column's value for any row which isn't actually affected by a DML statement.

Comment: Thanks. This makes perfect sense.